# Orthogonal projection of a line on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a line given with the vectorial form

$\Delta : [x\ y\ z] = [6\ {-1}\ 5] + k[11\ {-7}\ 13]$ where $k$ belongs to real

and the plane

$\Pi : 7x-3y+2z+7= 0$

They are asking to find the symetrical form of the orthogonal projection of the line delta in the plane.

I,m confuse since to do a OP I need 2 vectors and I don't find 2 in this problem who have the same or opposite direction, could I get some help

Comment: Isn't the other vector $\begin{pmatrix}
        7   \\
        -3   \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
?

Comment: that's the normal to the plane,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** One way could be: 1) find the point $A = \Delta \cap \Pi$; 2) chose a point $B$, s.t. $A \neq B \in \Delta$; 3) find the line $L$ that passes through $B$ and orthogonal to $\Pi$ (the normal vector to $\Pi$ is the direction vector of $L$); 4) find $C = L \cap \Pi$; 5) and now we have two points, $A$ and $C$, of the orthogonal projection of the line delta in the plane.

Comment: it's seems it didn't work.the vector AC isn't paralell to the vector director of the answer I've been given

Comment: Edit : I made a mistake and now I get a vector who have some similarities with the answer I look into and be back, thank

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the vectorial product between the director vector of the curve delta and the normal vector of the plane Pi. Then, you vould do another vectorial product between the new vector calculated and the normal vector of plane Pi. Finally, you could do the orthogonal projection of the director vector of Delta and the lastly calculated vector and get your symetrical form for the curve. I think it should work, but you'll have to try it.